# how to change basic html title tooltip background color without adding any extra span?

Tags: html, css, tooltip, bootstrap-5

How to change tooltip background color without adding extra span or div? I have a lot of tooltips across my projects. Is there any way to change bg color of all those by once ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body style="text-align:center;">


<div class="tooltip" title="tooltip text">Hover over me</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You didn't use any `bg` class in your snippet. If you didn't apply bootstrap bg classes, simply add your custom css : `.tooltip{background-color:orange;}`

Comment: @Cédric Thanks. but that's givign bg color to the text. Not tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

You can't style the title default tooltip with CSS.

You can add a pseudo-element :after the div.

The pseudo-element will be relative to the div, not to the text...
so it's not exactly the same.
You have to check all the positioning in the pages.

```css
<style>
    div[title]{
        position: relative;
    } 

    div[title]:hover:after{
        content: attr(title);
        background: red; 
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 1em;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body style="text-align:center;">


<div class="tooltip" title="tooltip text">Hover over me</div>


</body>
</html>
```

And, if you'd like remove the original tooltip, just use a "data-title" attribute instead of the "title" attribute, both in HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the `CSS` property `background-color` for the `.tooltip` class?

As you have already created the `.tooltip` class, it would be convenient to just define its `background-color` property.

It would change the background color for all the elements with the `.tooltip` class at once.

Comment: Thanks. but that's givign bg color to the text. Not tooltip